# How to use lxde-pi.rc.xml file correctly?

Tags: file

I try to create keyboard shorcuts by editing files, since there is no GUI for it

I have these 3 files:

```
24.6K /etc/xdg/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml modified few months ago
23.6K /etc/xdg/openbox/rc.xml modified 2019
2.4K /home/pi/.config/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml modified yesterday
```

All instructions i have found from net tells to copy that first file to /home/pi/.config/openbox/.

But it deletes all settings that are in /home/pi/.config/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml.

So should i just copy it over old file?

Answer (score 0):

The official instruction say use Appearance Settings/Defaults to setup Desktop.

Yes this does clobber any existing settings. There is no easy way to configure most settings, as Simon Long removed the tool to allow this, and the Foundation has refused to implement a tool to allow this. (Admittedly the original tool had some issues with the Foundation implementation)

```
cp ~/.config/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml ~/.config/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml.orig
```

See https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=229080&hilit=openbox for some discussion of this.

If you have customised it executing Appearance Settings/Default will clobber your settings and the openbox tool doesn't work.

The good news is that it can be manually configured.

Make a backup copy of /home/pi/.config/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml - this can be restored.
Copy /etc/xdg/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml (or run Appearance Settings/Default). You will now have a Windows like screen, which can be configured in .config/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml.

NOTE I believe customising the settings (without running Appearance Settings/Default) updates the system wide settings (which then get clobbered at next update. If you explore and compare versions you may be able to find where these are stored.

It is not difficult to manipulate the settings by manually editing your copy (otherwise you are stuck with the Windows like settings.

See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/122127/8697 for some hints.